# Mui Datepicker accepts incorrect format (yyyy-MM-dd)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Mui datepicker, with the format yyyy-MM-dd.
If the user writes the a value with only one day (yyyy-MM-d), like 2020-12-1, this get converted to 2020-12-01.

Is there a way to assert that the user has to write two digits?

[Here is a link to the datepicker demo where you can see how it works.](https://codesandbox.io/s/materialuipickers-material-demo-forked-336he?file=/demo.js:806-936)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use third party library to help with form validation. For example, [React hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/). `DatePicker` API exposes `inputRef` so this is possible.

Comment: I'm using react hook form. There is an issue that DatePicker formats the value before it reaches the validation used by react hook form.